# we want to prove that $(n,n+1) \cap \mathbb{N}$ is empty

Tags: real-analysis, induction, solution-verification, natural-numbers

## Problem: prove that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $(n,n+1) \cap \mathbb{N} = \varnothing $

## attempt:

Indeed, let $S(n)$ be the statement $\{ n : (n,n+1) \cap \mathbb{N} = \varnothing \}$. Clearly, $(1,2) \cap \mathbb{N} = \varnothing$, thus $1 \in S(n)$. Assume now that $S(n)$ is true. Then,

$$ (n+1,n+2) \cap \mathbb{N} =  (n,n+1) \cap (\mathbb{N} \setminus [n+1,n+2) ) \cap \mathbb{N} = (n,n+1) \cap \mathbb{N} \cap ( \mathbb{N} \setminus [n+1,n+2) ) = \varnothing $$

and the claim follows by the principle of mathematical induction.

Is this correct proof?

Comment: Why is the first equality true?

Comment: Such questions are always a waste of mathematical time.

Comment: why is a waste ?

Comment: "Clearly $(1,2) \cap \mathbb N = \emptyset$".  Why?  Why aren't there any natural numbers between $1$ and $2$?

Comment: "$(n+1,n+2)\cap \mathbb N= (n,,n+1)\cap (\mathbb N\setminus[n+1,n+2))\cap \mathbb N$"  What the funk?????  So if we has $A\cap X$ would you claim it is $B \cap (X\setminus A)\cap X$?  Why, would you claim such thing?

Comment: I dont know what I was thinkin

Comment: Okay.... so $0$ is the first natural number.  ANd $S(0) = 1$ is the sucessor of $0$ is the first natural number that is a successor.  If there were any natural number $m \in (0,1)$ then $m\ne 0$ so $m=s(n)$ is a successor of some natural $n$. But that is not the case as $1$ is the first successor.  If we assume that $(k,k+1)$ contain no natural number for $0\le k\le n$ then for there to be a natural number $m\in (n+1, n+2)$ then $m$ must be a success to some $m-1 \in (n+1-1, n+2-1)=(n,n+1)$ which is can not be.